# BotFramework: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, bots, botframework

**Issue:** Bot started showing me an error, when using the emulator. While i am not sure, i think the emulator might have been updated

**Debugging** I checked that the AppID and secret are correct.

**Error:**

```
-> POST 401 [conversationUpdate]

Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect. 

Edit your bot's MSA info
```

**web.config Info:**

```
<!-- update these with your appid and one of your appsecret keys-->
<add key="MicrosoftAppID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="YYYYYYYYYY" />
<!--Azure Credentials (V1 Authentication Mode) -->
<add key="ActiveDirectory.Mode" value="v1" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ResourceId" value="https://graph.windows.net/" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.EndpointUrl" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.Tenant" value="ZZZZZZZ" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ClientId" value="aaa" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.ClientSecret" value="bbb" />
<add key="ActiveDirectory.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:25601/api/OAuthCallback" />
```

Comment: If you are running the bot locally, then the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword should be empty (unless you are using ngrok, and you've changed the Messaging Endpoint to point to your local machine).

Comment: Thank you Eric, it edit my webconfig debug and release. But, why it works until now? Something change on emulator?

Comment: I don't think anything changed in the emulator related to running locally.  As far as I know, in order to debug locally without setting up ngrok, it has always been necessary to clear out the appid and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the Microsoft APP ID and Microsoft App Password values empty both in web.config file and the emulator when debugging locally.

[image: Like this]

and in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- update these with your BotId, Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
    <add key="BotId" value="YourBotId" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: I have clean the data on web.config, but when I need to deploy to azure I must insert the IDs and when is to test locally, I must remove the IDs. Is there some way to do that automaticly? I had try to add in web.release.config the ids and removed on web.debug.config, but did not work.

Comment: The recommended way is to use Application Settings in the Azure portal, and you should find that they are already populated there.  If you click on your bot in the portal, then 'Application Settings' menu, scroll down to the 'App Settings' section you should see them.  These will override anything in your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty project with Bot template(or use existing bot project) and update the bot builder version from Visual studio NuGet package to latest version. **Try to test it with latest bot emulator** 
(https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/) it should work