# Microsoft teams echo bot sample keeps failing with "access_token" error

Tags: python, botframework

I am having very consistent issues as it relates to the access_token with my teams bot. I am using the "02.echo-bot" sample written in python.

When I go to Azure portal -> app registrations -> my app -> certificates & services, my "value" in the only client secret I have is consistent with `APP_PASSWORD` in my `config.py` file. My `APP_ID` value is also consistent as what I have on the Overview page for Application (client) ID.

I've got ngrok set up correctly to forward traffic to the server that is spun up by `app.py` and I can see traffic flowing when I send messages from the "Test" tab of the bot framework web page.

However, every time I send a message, I see the following error:

```
root@test:~/teams-bot-test/botbuilder-samples/samples/python/02.echo-bot# python3 app.py 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/schema/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: The Bot Framework Python SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending in November 2023, after which this repository will be archived. There will be no further feature development, with only critical security and bug fixes within this repository being undertaken. Existing bots built with this SDK will continue to function. For all new bot development we recommend that you adopt Power Virtual Agents.
  warn(
======== Running on http://localhost:3978 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)

 [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
    return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
    return await callback(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
    await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
  File "/root/teams-bot-test/botbuilder-samples/samples/python/02.echo-bot/bots/echo_bot.py", line 17, in on_message_activity
    return await turn_context.send_activity(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity
    result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities
    return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit
    return await logic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic
    responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 735, in send_activities
    raise error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 720, in send_activities
    response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 524, in reply_to_activity
    response = await self._client.async_send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/msrest/async_client.py", line 115, in async_send
    pipeline_response = await self.config.pipeline.run(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 159, in run
    return await first_node.send(pipeline_request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 79, in send
    response = await self.next.send(request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_requests.py", line 99, in send
    self._creds.signed_session(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
    auth_token = self.get_access_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
    return auth_token["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

This issue seems to be consistent with an incorrect app password, according to other articles that I've seen; however, I've confirmed and double checked this several times. I've even created a new client secret to get a new secret, and it still gives me the exact same error.

Setting this test up seems to be relatively easy and minimal configuration changes. What else would be contributing to this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. The python sample 02.echo-bot ran successfully with provided `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`.

Comment: I'm curious on why it's failing with "access_token" error. The 02.echo-bot sample does not do any OAuth authentication. Have you made any code changes to the bot?

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't appear to be documented other than solutions to problems via Q&A, it now works when removing the App ID and App Password. I assume these values must remain empty when debugging empty, according to [BotFramework: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046470/botframework-the-bots-msa-appid-or-password-is-incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

For `MicrosoftAppPassword` in config.py, could you please verify if you are using 'Value' for the secret and not `SecretID` in Azure App registration Certificate & secrets page:
[image]